# how do you handle click events in a slickgrid custom editor?

Tags: slickgrid

I have a custom editor in slickgrid that looks like:

[image]

The custom editor code looks like:

```
function GroupsSelectEditor(args) {
    var $groups;
    var defaultValue;

    this.init = function () {
      $groups = $("<div class=\"editor-groups\">" +
              "<ul>"+
                  "<li><input type='checkbox'> group1</li>" +
                  "<li><input type='checkbox'> group2</li>" +
                  "<li><input type='checkbox'> group3</li>" +
                  "<li><input type='checkbox'> group4</li>" +
                  "<li><input type='checkbox'> group5</li>" +
              "</ul>" +
              "<button class=\"btn btn-mini\" >done</button>" +
            "</div");
      $groups.appendTo(args.container);
    };

    this.destroy = function () {
      $groups.remove();
    };

    // ...
  }
```

And the column in question uses this custom editor:

```
columns = [
    {id: "groups", name: "Groups", field: "groups", editor: GroupsSelectEditor},
];
```

I want the "done" button to dismiss the "$groups" div element, presumably by calling the destroy() function.

What is the best way to do this? I know slickgrid uses its own events, but I don't know how to make my button participate, or if that's even appropriate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that you don't have to participate using slickgrid events. The correct way to dispose of the current active editor is by calling this grid function:

```
grid.getEditController().commitCurrentEdit();
```

Below is the modified code where the DOM is constructed in a piecewise manner, and a click handler is bound to the button, which calls this `commitCurrentEdit()` function.

```
function (args) {
    var $groups;
    var defaultValue;

    this.init = function () {
      $groups = $("<div class=\"editor-groups\"></div>");
      var ul = $("<ul></ul>");
      $groups.append(ul);
      for (var i=0;i<5;i++) {
          var li = $("<li><input type='checkbox'> group"+i+"</li>");
          ul.append(li);
      }
      var btn = $("<button class=\"btn btn-mini\" >done</button>");
      btn.click(function() {
          args.grid.getEditController().commitCurrentEdit();
      });
      $groups.append(btn);
      $groups.appendTo(args.container);
      $groups.focus();
    };

    this.destroy = function () {
      $groups.remove();
    };

    ...
    ...

   }
```

Note there is also a `cancelCurrentEdit()` you could call.